# Выровнять float'ы в сетке

Tags: html, css

Есть код:

```
<div class="container">
<li class="block2"></li>
<ul class="posts first">
<li class="block"></li>
<li class="block"></li>
<li class="block"></li>
<li class="block"></li>
<li class="block"></li>
<li class="block"></li>
<li class="block"></li>
<li class="block"></li>
<li class="block"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="posts second">
<li class="block"></li>
<li class="block"></li>
<li class="block"></li>
<li class="block"></li>
<li class="block"></li>
<li class="block"></li>
<li class="block"></li>
<li class="block"></li>
```

И css:

```
 container{
  width:940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding:40px;
  background:grey;
}
.container:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.block{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  width:216px;
  height:186px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 22px;
  list-style: none;
}
.block2{
  float:right;
  border:1px solid #fff;
  clear:both;
  width:217px;
  height:603px;
  list-style:none;
}
.posts{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.first .block:nth-child(3n+1){
  margin-left:0px;
  clear:left;
}
.second .block:nth-child(4n+1){
  margin-left:0px;
  clear:left;
}
```

При разрешении браузера в 100% все выглядит правильно, но если начать менять разрешение окна до 25% то вся сетка сьезжает, подскажите как можно исправить это, что бы сетка была такой же ровной как при разрешении в 100% Код на фидле: https://jsfiddle.net/92j5yr6c/1/

Answer (score 1):

Вы каждому первому из трех элементов убрали левый отступ, а когда сужаете, то ваши 3n+1 уже не катит. Или убирайте у всех левый отступ или у всех ставьте или решайте проблему с помощью медиа-зарпосов, но это уже адаптивная верстка. Тогда наверняка будет работать именно так, как вы хотите. Вот, если кратко:

```
@media (max-width: 950px){
    .block:nth-child(2n+1){
        margin-left:0px!important;
        clear:left!important;
    }
    .block:nth-child(3n+1){
        margin-left:0px!!important;
        clear:left!important;
    } 
}

@media (max-width: 709px){
    .block{
       margin-left:0px!important;
       clear:left!important;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/92j5yr6c/6/
на моем экране все срабатывает ровно

Answer (score 0):

Как-то тут с версткой у вас закручено. Попробуйте [этот вариант](https://jsfiddle.net/k2ef2job/):

```
.posts {
  display: table;
}
.block {
  display: table-cell;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width:216px;
    height:186px;
    margin: 0 0 20px 22px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете исправить с помощью **@media** запросов для стилей **:nth-child**, изменив *3n+1* на *2n+1*, и для **.first** добавив margin-right.

Пример:

```
.container{
    width:940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:40px;
    background:grey;
}
.container:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.block{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width:216px;
    height:186px;
    margin: 0 0 20px 22px;
    list-style: none;
}
.block2{
    float:right;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    clear:both;
    width:217px;
    height:603px;
    list-style:none;
}
.posts{
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.first{
    margin-right: 220px;
}
@media (min-width: 920px){
.first .block:nth-child(3n+1){
    margin-left:0px;
    clear:left;
}
.second .block:nth-child(4n+1){
    margin-left:0px;
    clear:left;
}
}
@media (max-width: 919px){
first .block:nth-child(2n+1){
    margin-left:0px;
    clear:left;
}
.second .block:nth-child(3n+1){
    margin-left:0px;
    clear:left;
}  
}
```